# lib specified by LD_PRELOAD can not be loaded

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, shared, ldd, ld-preload

I met some trouble when using LD_PRELOAD to load my so.

The steps are as following:

1. libtest.c:

   ```
   void fun()
   {
       return 
   }
   ```
2. gcc -o libtest.so libtest.c -fPIC --shared
3. export LD_PRELOAD=`pwd`/libtest.so
4. main.c

   `extern void fun();
   void main()
   {
       fun()
   }`
5. gcc -o main -L. main.c -ltest
6. Then `ldd main`

   `ldd main
   linux-vdso.so.1=>(0x00007ffff7ffd000)
   /home/shiyanlou/Code/libtest.so(0x00007ffff7df9000)
   libtest.so=>not found
   libc.so.6=>/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffffa29000)
   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555555554000)`
7. execute main `./main`
   it promotes:
   error while loading shared library:libtest.so. cannot open shared object file:No such file or directory.

I wonder that why it prompts that libtest.so cannot be found After I exported LD_PRELOAD variable. However, I also tried to use LD_PRELOAD to specify a different shared lib(not "libc.so") to inject malloc function, it works! 
Why LD_PRELOAD only works for the shared lib that was not used when linking???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 2 versions of the *.so.  One which has default behavior and is loaded and hard linked via "-ltest".

Now build your default libtest.so and prove with `nm -B` the symbol you are expecting to intercept is dynamically linked.

Now build main.c into main.o, then check main.o with `nm` to also see it has an extern unsatisfied linkage requirement on the symbol.

Now link `./main` with main.o and libtest.so and then run it.
The `./main` needs to run with this copy by default, demonstrate the default behavior and also show the correct path to the correct DSO via `ldd` command.

...

Now you take the step to create the LD_PRELOAD version.

You shall call this `libtest2.so`.  You do not use the `-ltest2`

The point is that whoever built `./main` does not know about libtest2.so at all, there is no hard linkage dependency.

libtest2.so has alternative behavior, like make foo() returns a different string/number) and the goal now is to intercept this 2nd version at runtime, so the 1st version is not called by default (or at all).  By using the LD_PRELOAD environment.

`LD_PRELOAD=./libtest2.so ./main`

...

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thans for your help. I know your method works. But I just want to know why LD_PRELOAD does not works for the lib which I used to link my executable program?

Comment: Because it is already loaded? `-ltest` make a hard DSO dependency and that is not what LD_PRELOAD Is about.  You misunderstand the purpose.  Maybe if you copy to another name and load that instead. `cp libtest.so libtest9.so` then `LD_PRELOAD=./libtest9.so ./main`  Since `libtest.so` is already loaded hence the `/home/shiyanlou/Code/libtest.so(0x00007ffff7df9000)` by default the dynamic linker will only load a DSO once into the process address space. By copying the file it becomes a different DSO.

Comment: Thans for your further explanation.                                                        In sumary, I use `libtest.so` to make a hard DSO dependency, and LD_PRELOAD is also set to `/home/shiyanlou/Code/libtest.so`. When I execute ./main, it will load `libtest.so` because of hard DSO dependency rather than LD_PRELOAD. And then LD_PRELOAD will be ignored as the same DSO has already been loaded. In consequence, the libtest.so is actually not loaded, and `./main` could not be executed. Am I right? If so, why LD_PRELOAD is named LD_PRELOAD? Shouldn't it be loaded before any other DSO??

Comment: Am not here to debate why it is named as it is.  But in short you are asking for the same DSO to be loaded (both as a hard dependency and as LD_PRELOAD) and it does get loaded.  So what is the issue?  What is important is does the LD_PRELOAD get loaded ? and does it manage to intercept the symbols ?  Since the answers are yes and yes, what does it matter that it looks like it was loaded via the hard dependency since the observable behavior of the executable is the same.  Now copy and rename the DSO and observe again.

Comment: I think I figured it out why it could not work. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and rename the DSO as libtest2.so and reset LD_PRELOAD to the renamed DSO(with absolute path), It also prompt that libtest.so could not be found.

I think that the reason why it prompt so is that the libtest.so which is used for hard dependency could not be loaded.

That is to say while LD_PRELOAD has been loaded, but hard dependency could not be satisfied, so it could not execute `./main` either.

Now I can conclude that when execute ./main, hard dependency DSO must be satisfied because every hard dependency DSO also must be loaded(although this DSO shall be totally replaced!), otherwise it will prompt that the DSO could not be found!

Thanks for your help @Darryl Miles

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why your example not working is that your `libtest.so` does not have the correct soname.

If you compile your `libtest.c` with the following command

```
$ gcc -o libtest.so libtest.c -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so
```

then you should be able to execute your `main` with `PRELOAD`.